# Using Block with objectAtIndex method of NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

Here is the code:

```
TrailLayer * layer = (TrailLayer*)[_layers objectAtIndex:(int)^{
    if (_segmentNumber < [_segmentArray count]) {
        return _segmentNumber;
    } else {
        return _segmentNumber - 1;
    }
}];
```

what is the problem here? Here, all the _Variables are IVARs. I am first time using Blocks, can someone help me identifying this problem. Its giving EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION here.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is wrong `return _segmentNumber - 1;` suppose the `segmenNumber` is much bigger than array count...

Comment: for the fact of the matter, i know _segmentNumber can only be greater by 1 than array count.

Comment: What is the problem here???

Comment: Its giving EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION here.

Comment: Seems your _layers is deallocated...

Comment: I have NSZombieEnabled. Plus i rechecked all the IVARs, non is deallocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, First write block to get the `index` number, and use that number to retrieve value from `array`

```
int (^segmentIndex)(int) = ^(int segmentNumber){
        if (segmentNumber < [_layers count]) {
            return segmentNumber;
        } else {
            return segmentNumber - 1;
        }
};


NSLog(@"Trail Layer %@", [_layers objectAtIndex:segmentIndex(_segmentNumber)]);
TrailLayer * layer = (TrailLayer*)[_layers objectAtIndex:segmentIndex(_segmentNumber)];
```

Comment: It worked Thanks :)
Though can you identify the problem in my code? what is wrong with using Blocks directly?

Comment: There's no problem with using blocks, except that you didn't call the block. You passed the block to the method, when you should have passed the return value of the block.

Answer (score 1):

A block is a runnable thing like a function, basically a piece of code that you can store, pass around, and run later (or not). You want to pass an integer to `objectAtIndex:`, so passing a block makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

What you could have meant to do was *run* the block, and then pass *its result* to `objectAtIndex:`. In that case, you would have to run the block:

```
TrailLayer * layer = [_layers objectAtIndex:^{
    if (_segmentNumber < [_segmentArray count]) {
        return _segmentNumber;
    } else {
        return _segmentNumber - 1;
    }
}()]; // <-- run the block
```

However, defining a block (which is a full-fledged object, and does a lot of fancy stuff) just to run it immediately is kinda silly. If you want to just be able to use a piece of code as an expression, you could use the "statement expressions" language extension supported by both GCC and LLVM:

```
TrailLayer * layer = [_layers objectAtIndex:({
    int result;
    if (_segmentNumber < [_segmentArray count]) {
        result = _segmentNumber;
    } else {
        result = _segmentNumber - 1;
    }
    result;
})];
```

But really you should just do a regular C conditional expression in this case:

```
TrailLayer * layer = [_layers objectAtIndex:
                      _segmentNumber < [_segmentArray count] ?
                      _segmentNumber : _segmentNumber - 1];
```

Comment: Great Answer, though in the end i ended up using the ternary at that time, but as i was using the Bocks for the first time, its was really bugging me that what could have gone wrong there. Though your point is absolutely right here that its silly to use a block in my case.
Anyway, thanks a lot, this helped really :)